# GWT VerticalPanel Align problems

Tags: css, gwt

i'm trying to figure out how i could align the childs of a verticalPanel as i want.

I have a verticalPanel with 100% height which is added to center of a splitLayoutPanel. 
When adding the first child in the verticalPanel it automaticaly aligns to the top.
After setting the hight of the child widget to for example 30PX and adding another child, the second one aligns to the top of the half hight of the verticalPanel.

I would like to be the second child (scrollPanel) aligned right under the first one considering the spacing and the scrollPanel should use 100% of the rest from the verticalPanel heigt.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the height of the second cell to 100%, e.g.:

```
myVerticalPanel.setCellHeight(myScrollPanel, "100%");
```

Alternatively, you could replace the VerticalPanel by a DockPanel (or DockLayoutPanel) and add the first child north and the second child in the center.

Comment: same problem here... edit: ok, sorry, working if i change the cell-propertys

Answer (score 0):

What I think happening is this,

A vertical panel is implemented as a table when rendered,  so when you set height of vertical panel to 100% it sets the height of the table to 100%. When you add an item to it,  the 1st item is added to a  which effectively takes up the 100% height, and inside that the added child is set to height 30px. Now when you add another child to the panel another  is created. Now the vertical panel ie the table has two rows so it distributes the height equally ie 50% to reach row, hence you observe the behavior of getting added to top of half height.

A simple solution to this would be to use FlowPanel(with 10%% width and height) and have your child added to it take width as 100% and height for 1st child as 30px and 2nd child with width and height both 100%. Hope that helps you.